# Function to get (print) the sequence of a structure in SQL database

Tags: sql, structure

I have a data base that is like

| Cap | Sec | Art |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | I | 1 |
| I | II | 2 |
| II | I | 3 |
| II | II | 4 |
| II | III | 5 |
| ... |  |  |

and I want to get a function that prints me

```
Cap I
Sec I
Art 1
Sec II
Art 2
Cap II
Sec I
Art 3
Sec II
Art 4
Sec III
Art 5
...
```

I've tried to use the "group by" and nesting but i'm not getting there

Any suggestions

Best regards

Comment: Voting to close as not clear what you are asking.

Comment: My question may have not been clear. I don't want to repeat the lines in Cap and Sec once they have been placed. The code you showed results in
cap I
sec I
art 1
cap I
sec II
art 2
cap II
sec I
art 3
cap II
sec II
art 4
cap II
sec III
art 5 

I'm looking for

cap I
sec 1
art 1
sec II
art 2
cap II
sec I
art 3
sec II
art 4
sec III
art 5